# Why is my php -v version different from phpinfo()?

Tags: php, ssh

I looked at some of the similar questions and they have a similar problem except their `php -v` version is the one that is higher than the `phpinfo()` reported version. For when I call `phpinfo()` from php file it shows 5.5.25 which is correct. In the terminal through ssh I run `php -v` and it gives me 5.4.43. I'm using GoDaddy hosting and on cPanel I have it set to 5.5. I'm using Composer and Laravel. When I create a new Laravel project it gives me this error:

```
[~/public_html]$ laravel new blog
Crafting application...
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> php artisan clear-compiled
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:



run-script [--dev] [--no-dev] [-l|--list] [script] [args1] ... [argsN]


Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

Comment: Kindly check that what is the version of php in your composer.json file.

Comment: I checked my composer.json file and it says that it "requre" php 5.5.9 but it doesn't say anywhere where it is fetching the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different path to get to the right version of the command line PHP.

Use

> which -a php

To get the paths to the available versions of PHP, then use the full pathname.

For example

> /usr/bin/php5

Comment: Ah it appears, that usr/bin/php is the correct one and the /usr/local/bin/php is incorrect

Comment: Would it be safe to remove the /usr/local/bin/php?

Comment: You can create an alias to php that will point to the version you need, but I recommend you use the full path to the version for clarity.  If you create an alias like **php55**, it would be good.

Comment: Alright, creating an alias worked although when I use composer to install a new laravel project or install dependencies it still says package requires >=5.5.9 but your php version is 5.4.43.

Comment: In that case, you are right, the best solution is to create an alias or symlink to **php** that points to the version you need.

Comment: Why not just grab the path to php directly from the phpinfo output and use that path, rather than making aliases and trying to figure out pathing?

Comment: @Jesse I need composer to recognize the correct PHP version and it seems to be looking at the wrong path. I'm not sure where to configure composer to look at the right path however. Create an alias 'php' works for php -v but composer is still looking at the wrong php path.

Comment: yes, I did that and made sure to exit terminal and re-enter. It works in that when I do php -v it gives the correct version although when I run "composer install" it says my version is 5.4.

Comment: Try using **php composer.phar install**

Comment: I tried that and threw a bunch of errors. I also tried php-cgi which also has a version of 5.5.25. I think it might be something wrong on GoDaddy's end that I might not have permissions for. I even went to the phpinfo site, grabbed the path from there and that didn't work either. Anyways, you answered my main question and I think I will mess around with it locally and see if I can deploy it on remote server. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - **/usr/bin/php composer.phar install**